# What is the square-root of the nonnegative self-adjoint operator $L^2\to L^2,f\mapsto\int f$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space. Since $\mathbb R$ is naturally embedded into $L^2(\mu)$, we may consider the operator $$U:L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\mu)\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto\int f\:{\rm d}\mu.$$ Obviously, $U$ is nonnegative and self-adjoint. Thus, there is a unique square-root $Q^{1/2}:L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\mu)$. But what's the explicit form of $Q^{1/2}$?

Comment: See the wiki on fractional calculus, and integration in particular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of a constant with respect to a probability measure is itself.  So $U^2 = U$ and thus $U$ is its own square root.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But if we take a look at the finite-dimensional case, $E=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and $\mathcal E=2^E$, then $\mu$ may be treat as a vector in $\mathbb R^k$ and $U$ is the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k)$. The square-root of this matrix is obviously not the matrix itself. What am I missing?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: $U$ is not a diagonal matrix.  It's the rank-1 matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \mu_1 & \dots & \mu_k \\ \mu_1 & \dots & \mu_k \\ & \vdots & \\ \mu_1 & \dots & \mu_k \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've confused this. The diagonal matrix, call it $D$, is such that $\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=g^TDf$, where $f,g$ are identified with vectors in $\mathbb R^k$. How is $U$ related to the inner product?

Comment: I guess you could say $U = 1 1^T D$, where $1$ is the vector of all 1s.  Or in other words, $Uf = \langle 1, f \rangle_{L^2(\mu)} 1$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You can also think in terms of spectral decompositions.  If we let $e_1$ be the constant function $1 \in L^2(\mu)$, then $e_1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 1$.  And if $\langle f, e_1 \rangle = 0$ then clearly $\int f\,d\mu = 0$, so if we extend $e_1$ to any orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, \dots$, then all $e_i$, $i \ge 2$, are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_i = 0$.  Then $Uf = \sum_i \lambda_i \langle f, e_i \rangle e_i$. [...]

Comment: Now by the functional calculus, $U^{1/2} f$ must be given by $\sum_i \lambda_i^{1/2} \langle f, e_i \rangle e_i$.  But every eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is either 0 or 1 and thus $\lambda_i^{1/2} = \lambda_i$, so $U^{1/2}$ is just $U$ again.

Comment: I begin to understand. So, $U$ is a compact operator ... The $e_1,e_2,\ldots$ are supposed to be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mu)$, right? (Note that, in the general case, we need some separability assumption on $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$) How would an orthonormal basis of $\{f\in L^2(\mu):\mu f=0\}$ look like? (I guess I need such an orthonormal basis in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3380362/47771.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, correct, the $e_i$ should be an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mu)$.  What they might looks like depends on what the measure is, and of course the basis is highly non-unique.  As a couple examples, for $[0,1]$ with $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, you can take $\sqrt{2} \cos(n \pi x)$, $n \ge 1$, as an orthonormal basis of the subspace of functions with mean zero.  For standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$, you can take the Hermite polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What would be the analogue of $\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k)$ in the general case?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Diagonal operators generally correspond to (pointwise) multiplication operators.  So on a finite measure space, your operator is just pointwise multiplication by the function $g$ defined by $g(k) = \mu_k$.  However, more generally, $\mu$ is a measure and does not correspond to any particular function, and it does not make sense to multiply a function by a measure, so there isn't really an "analogue" in general.